# Adobe Photoshop destroys image after loading

Tags: image, adobe, line, photoshop

I have a problem with my Photoshop version 13.0.1 x32. When I load something, it looks like that (it's fullscreen mode).

[image]

I don't know what to do. I tried reinstalling and updating, but nothing helped. It's Windows 10 x64, so could that be a problem? I also tried it on another machine also Windows 10 x64 and it works fine.

Another problem is that when Photoshop is in windowed mode, it loads images correctly, but the tool panel disappears.

Any suggestions on what to do?
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: A proper place for this question will be probably a https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com, stackoverflow is for coding questions. But my guess is it's a video card or drivers problem.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I'll take a look on it. I'll post it on stackexchange and delete it here.